# Manhua of cultivation where the main character was the master of several different sect leaders

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I recently read a manhua in which the MC was the master of several leaders from different sects, the MC goes to his disciple's sect and goes through a test in front of a statue that, when he touches it,
it shatters and an extra starts accusing the MC of having
it was intentionally destroyed and soon afterwards an elder from the sect arrives and asks about what happened and the extra responds that the MC destroyed the statue of the ancestor/founder of the society, but soon the elder receives a message from the ancestor of the sect telling him to treat the boy well,
then he passes the test and the elder starts to treat him and receives another message to meet with the ancestor and tell another teacher to continue the test, the teacher then asks what type of class he would like to enter (there are 4 rooms I I think) and he chooses alchemy,
the teacher who teaches alchemy is treated badly by the other teachers who say that she never managed to meet the goal of students transcending in her classroom and says that she will lose all the resources in her classroom.

Well that's what I remember since I saw this work about 6 months ago and I don't remember its name, that's why I'm asking for help :)